# Find the first occurence of a vowel in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a function `isvowel` that returns either `True` or `False`, depending on whether a character `ch` is a vowel.

```
    def isvowel(ch):
          if "aeiou".count(ch) >= 1:
              return True
          else:
              return False
```

I want to know how to use that to get the index of the first occurrence of any vowel in a string. I want to be able to take the characters before the first vowel and add them end of the string. Of course, I can't do `s.find(isvowel)` because `isvowel` gives a boolean response. I need a way to look at each character, find the first vowel, and give the index of that vowel.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: This seems extremely similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544302/python-string-and-lists/  Many of the answers there involve determining the index of the 1st vowel occurrence in a string.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Pig Latin converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[isvowel(ch) for ch in string].index(True)
```

Comment: From an efficiency POV this isn't ideal, if you have the string "a" followed by 1000 characters, then you'll have to process all 1001 characters through `isvowel()` even though you could know after only looking at the 1st.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very simplistic solution. @Adam the string will have no more than 50 characters

Comment: I agree with Adam. I wish list comprehension has way to break early.

Comment: Even if the string will not have too many characters, it is wise to use a more efficient solution simply it can often times come in handy in the future should you decide to further expand/develop your project. Having said that, the choice is really yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try something like this:

```
import re

def first_vowel(s):
    i = re.search("[aeiou]", s, re.IGNORECASE)
    return -1 if i == None else i.start()

s = "hello world"
print first_vowel(s)
```

Or, if you don't want to use regular expressions:

```
def first_vowel(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if isvowel(s[i].lower()):
            return i
    return -1

s = "hello world"
print first_vowel(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(ch for ch in string if isvowel(ch)).next()
```

or for just the index (as asked):

```
(index for ch, index in itertools.izip(string, itertools.count()) if isvowel(ch)).next()
```

This will create an iterator and only return the first vowel element. Warning: a string with no vowels will throw `StopIteration`, recommend handling that.

Comment: Since I think the OP needs the index, something like `next(i for i,c in enumerate(s) if isvowel(c))` would probably work better.

Comment: Yep, pretty easy change. I do like your use of enumerate(s) better than using itertools, I'll remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

```
>>> vowel_str = "aeiou"

>>> def isVowel(ch,string):
...     if ch in vowel_str and ch in string:
...             print string.index(ch)
...     else:
...             print "notfound"
... 
>>> isVowel("a","hello")
not found

>>> isVowel("e","hello")
1
>>> isVowel("l","hello")
not found

>>> isVowel("o","hello")
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using next for a generator is quite efficient, it means you don't iterate though the entire string (once you have found a string).

```
first_vowel(word):
    "index of first vowel in word, if no vowels in word return None"
    return next( (i for i, ch in enumerate(word) if is_vowel(ch), None)
is_vowel(ch):
    return ch in 'aeiou'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = 'Bla bla'
vowels = 'aeyuioa'

def find(my_string):
    for i in range(len(my_string)):
        if my_string[i].lower() in vowels:
            return i
            break 

print(find(my_string))
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".