# Extract the index of the first vowel in a string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to find any vowels that comes first from the word. Output should be same with the output of the find() function.

So, for example,

from "python", output should be "4" ("python".find("o") is 4)

from "stock", output should be "2"

from "overflow", output should be "0"

from "styling", output should be "4" ("styling".find("i") is 4)

Actually What I am really trying to do is to remove vowel that comes first,

```
    while 0 != 1:
     if word[x] in 'aeiou':
       word = word[x]+word[x+2:]
       x = x+1
    else: x = x+1
```

This is what I have been trying so far, but it causes "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Any solution starts with writing some code.

Comment: Have you tried simple ```for``` loop ?

Comment: You should be looking for `next` and `enumerate`. Show us what you've tried and we'll tell you where you're going wrong. There's a nice one liner but I don't think you should be entitled to it until you show that you've genuinely tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `next` is tricky here: what if there are _no_ vowels? stopiteration exception.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Mmh, fair point.

Comment: I would have used regular expressions and `start()` method of the match object if not `None`. the question is interesting. but there's a downvoting ring on that one, so better close it, quick

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ @Jean-FrançoisFabre You can always use the `next(it, default)` argument, but I prefer a loop instead of `next`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To the rescue! It works so nicely, I wish I could write it here, but OP doesn't deserve it :( Maybe I should write a self answered question...

Comment: at least we learned something from juanpa because of that question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually, I found a dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554917/in-python-how-can-i-use-string-find-to-find-the-first-occurence-of-a-vowel-and Do the honours? I already VTC'd...

Comment: thanks but I also VTCd. Too impulsive... note that you could post your solution, since the answers are feeble... did that once, and garnered 8 upvotes in a few months...

Comment: @Siddharth Yes, but it's causing "TypeError: must be str, not generator"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Welp, OP seems to have tried something. Guess that's a green light.

Comment: well, since it's a blatant duplicate that you exposed yourself, I wouldn't go for it. Personally I'm against this "OP hasn't tried anything" rule... Most of the time OP tries something but doesn't post it. That doesn't make the question bad. Question upvoted, CV retracted (but still needs hammering)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Okay I've edited my post and posted what I was working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a simple [**For loop**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) which you might be familiar with and [**enumerate**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def position_of_first_vowel(word):
  for index, char in enumerate(word):
    if char in 'aeiou':
      return index
  return -1

for case in ["python","stock", "overflow", "styling", "zxc"]:
  print("%s: %d" % (case, position_of_first_vowel(case)))
```

**Output:**

```
python: 4
stock: 2
overflow: 0
styling: 4
zxc: -1
```

**N.B.** The extra test case of `zxc` is there to show the returning of `-1` if a vowel does not occur in the word

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution using regex:

```
import re

VOWEL_REGEX = re.compile(r'[aeiou]')


def first_vowel_index(word):
    match = VOWEL_REGEX.search(word)
    if not match:
        return -1
    return match.start()
```

Tested for your examples:

```
>>> first_vowel_index('python')
4
>>> first_vowel_index('stock')
2
>>> first_vowel_index('overflow')
0
>>> first_vowel_index('styling')
4
```

Comment: yeah, that is the one I didn't post.

Answer (score 2):

This should be an easy one liner with `next` and `enumerate`.

```
def foo(string):
    next((i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c in set('aeiou')), -1)
```

---

```
inputs = ["python", "stock", "overflow", "styling", "pythn"] # note the last string
print([foo(i) for i in inputs])
[4, 2, 0, 4, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the for the first appearance, you can use the .index() method for strings.

```
string = "Foo Bar"
vocals = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
def first_index(string, chars):
    try:
        return min(string.index(vocal) for vocal in chars if vocal in string)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
print(first_index(string, vocals))
```

Returns:

```
1
```